# how to install debian7.5 from hard disk in win7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, debian

I have installed win7 in my disk `c:`,and the file system format is ntfs.
there is another disk `e:` (fat32 format).
I have download grub4dos,and `initrd.gz`, `vmlinuz`,and `debian7.5.iso` in `c:`.

1. edit the `boot.ini`

   ```
   [boot loader]    
   [operating systems]    
   c:\grldr.mbr="Grub4dos"
   ```
2. edit the `menu.lst`

   ```
   title    Install Debian 7.5    
   kernel    (hd0,0)/vmlinuz     
   initrd    (hd0,0)/initrd.gz    
   boot
   ```

when rebooting my pc, i can enter grub ui, click "Install Debian 7.5", get error:

```
kernel    (hd0,0)/vmlinuz   file not found.
```

Maybe the reason is filesystem format, `debian7.5.iso` and `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` can not be read under ntfs, so i cut the files into `e:` disk, how to edit the `menu.lst` now?

It is a typo ,i fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`(hdD,P)` means "hard drive (hence **hd**) device → device number `D` → partition number `P`". GRUB numbers devices (inside their class) and partitions (inside a device) starting from 0.

In your entry for the initrd image you've got this right: `(hd0,0)` selects the first partition of the first hard drive device, but in your entry for the kernel you for some reason dropped the partition number, and `(hd0,)` has no sense (`(hd0)` does but it refers to the whole device which you don't want if your device has partitions).

So I'd say the fix is to change

```
kernel (hd0,)/vmlinuz
```

to

```
kernel (hd0,0)/vmlinuz
```

Note that this change should fix the situation for volume `C:`.  If you want this to apply to volume `E:` you have to deduce which hard drive and partision number on it the volume `E:` uses and fix those `(hd0,0)` to read something like `(hd0,2)`.

To get this information, the easiest (probably) is to use the `diskpart` Windows tool:

1. Start the command prompt, `cmd.exe`, (possibly with elevated privileges—I don't know for sure).
2. There, run

   ```
   diskpart
   ```

   it presents you with its own shell, where you execute its commands. At any time you might enter `help` and hit the Return key to get help.

   The next steps are carried out in the `diskpart`'s shell.
3. Run

   ```
   list disk
   ```

   to get the numbered list of disks attached to the computer.  They are conveniently indexed starting with 0—just what GRUB uses.
4. Run

   ```
   select disk N
   ```

   where `N` is the number of disk you're interested in to change the tool's *context* to that disk.
5. Run

   ```
   list partition
   ```

   to get the list of partisions of the selected disk.  Note that the partitions are numbered from 1.
6. Run

   ```
   select partition M
   ```

   to change the tool's context to the partition number `M` *of the selected disk.*
7. Run

   ```
   detail partition
   ```

   to get the detailed information about the selected partition, including the volume letter it's attached as.

   Rinse and repeat until you've found the partition for your volume `E:`.  When you're done, you have two numbers to construct the `(hdD,P)` spec.

You can quit `diskpart` by entering `exit`.

Comment: how can i get all the file names in the selected partition?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, with `diskpart`? No way--it only deals with disks, partitions and volumes; not with file systems. But once you know the partition you need (`detail partition` called on it lists the volume you're looking for--say, `E:`), just fire up Windows Explorer and browse that volume (`E:`, that is).

Comment: i fount that when the drive number is 3 in diskpart ,you should minus 1 into 2 in your menu.lst.